# Eliminate page jump after video loads

Tags: html, css, wordpress, video-streaming

On this site, the top section of the page jumps down once the video loads. The video is hosted elsewhere.

https://prdwatchnextge.wpengine.com/

I believe it is because the height of the video isn't know until it fully loads and then the wrapper div expands to fit.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options really:

Either: Add a loading screen to your site that goes away when everything, including the video is loaded ()

Or, Preferably, give your video container a set height. Since you're using a 16:9, and the video element is set to `position: absolute`, you can actually remove the height and use a `padding-bottom` instead. This is how responsive video containers *usually* are done.

```
#botr_bw5Ao14B_sU6GI2rt_div {
    height: 0 !important;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}
```

Try adding the above CSS in your `Customizer > Additional CSS` section (or wherever you have custom CSS). I had to add `!important` to override the inline `height` style that's applied by the video player's JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Html5 video was pushing the content , but i added the css code provide by you and now CLS issue is gone.